# How to generate Red light from a Blue-Dominated Spectrum

Tags: visible-light, interference, biophysics, light-emitting-diodes

I have a white LED light source, the spectrum of which looks as follows ---

[image: White LED Spectrum]

I want to filter out red light from this white LED source. But as you can see the spectrum dwindles in the red zone.

And therefore, when I put red filter (absorptive filter) in front of my white LED light source, the brightness suddenly drops down to abysmal values.

Is there a way in which I could use this spectrum and get red lights without compromising on the brightness? I thought about interference and then I came across [dichroic filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filters).  But I'm not sure if that'll do it.

I also came across these filters called [LEE LED filters](http://www.leefilters.com/lighting/colour-details.html#CL164&filter=ld) which are filters specifically meant for LEDs. But I do not understand the scientific principle they work on. I would be grateful if you can follow the link and explain to me the scientific principle. From the spectrum shown in the link, these filters can give you more than 85% red. But the overall transmission is just 10.1% of the original intensity. So it's kinda bleh. Or maybe I don't understand properly.

A red LED light source would be just perfect for me, but a high wattage (50W-100W) red LED light source is hard to come across in the market.

Let me know if there are other options you guys can think of, for producing cool red LED light. Right now I use a tungsten lamp with RED absorptive filter, but there is so much heat (infrared) in it that my houseflies get fried up. [ *I work in an insect flight lab and we use red light for high speed videography, since houseflies dont see well in the red zone*]. So I want to switch to LEDs.

Comment: What about high-power RGB LED, using only red emmiter?

see: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/high-power-rgb-led

Comment: White LEDs generally work by using a blue LED to excite a phosphor, which generates the non-blue part of the spectrum. Other LEDs exist that generate red light directly, and they'll be much more efficient if you just want the red part of the spectrum. For example you might look into the ones used in traffic signal lights.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about Wave Length Shifters (WLS)? [ELJEN technology](http://www.ggg-tech.co.jp/maker/eljen/ej-280_4.html) produces two kinds of shifters, one shifting blue to green and one shifting green to red. So you could combine one WLS plate of each to get the optimal amount of red light.

However, the WLS will emit light omnidirectional. So half of the emitted green light won't hit the green-to-red WLS. And the result would definitely lack in coherence.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy multi-watt red LEDs for a few dollars each. This will be much more efficient than generating red light from blue or white light and trying to filter out the blue component.

Answer (score 1):

An off-the-shelf Philips Hue can easily be set to all-red and puts out a serious amount of light. Not perhaps 50W, but that's more easily solved by having more lights.

Another option would be to buy a strip of [red LEDs](http://www.superbrightleds.com/cat/flexible-strips-and-bars/filter/Color,Red,136,4639:). The linked product claims about 12W/meter, and sells 5 meters for USD 140. [Another product](http://www.ecolocityled.com/product/led_strip_50-50_r/led_strip_red) is 46W, but only USD 99.

Comment: How do you think the temperature of these strip LEDs would figure out?

Comment: LED is pretty efficient but still they'll be fairly hot locally - LED's are also small. I.e. you'd have an issue if your houseflies are attracted to IR.